# Pass vector of dates to quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I have the following vectors with tickers, start and end dates for which I want to download stock data with quantmod.

```
stock = c("MSFT", "WMT", "APPL")
start = c("2015-08-26", "2013-11-12","2015-11-08")
end = c("2015-09-26", "2013-12-12","2015-12-08")
```

I thought the following would work, but it only retrieves prices for the 3 stocks between 2015-08-26 and 2015-09-26.

```
library(quantmod)
stockData <- new.env()    
getSymbols(stock, env = stockData, src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end, verbose = T)
```

Is it not possible to pass vectors as dates to this function? Any elegant solutions are appreciated :)

Comment: Please give a reproducible code.

Comment: I missed to load the library and create the env. Reproducible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo doesn't recognize APPL so probably this should be changed to AAPL in `stock`.  After that you can create a character matrix from the `stock`, `start`, and `end` vectors and then call `getSymbols` for each row of the matrix.  Code would look like:

```
mat <- cbind(stock, start, end)
apply(mat, 1, function(x) getSymbols(Symbols=x["stock"], env=stockData2,
                                     src="yahoo", from=x["start"], to=x["end"], verbose=T))
attach(stockData2)
```